# Load unique data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got some json data which looks like below.

```
[
    {
        "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationTitle": "L",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 2,
        "LocationTitle": "L 2",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 3,
        "LocationTitle": "L 3",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 4,
        "LocationTitle": "L 4",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationTitle": "L 5",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 6,
        "LocationTitle": "L 6",
        "CountryCode": "HIJ",
        "Country": "V"
    }
]
```

What's the most efficient way to load the **unique Countries**, let's say into a dropdown?

So that the dropdown will only contains 3 items, which is G, M and V?

Comment: Unless you have thousands of different country letters, any solution will be sufficient enough.

Comment: Use a set, it's a one liner

Comment: sorry as I may not define my question clearly. what if I want to put the unique list to dropdown in which:
text = Country ; value = CountryCode ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/tL7263L7/

```js
var data = [
    {
        "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationTitle": "L",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 2,
        "LocationTitle": "L 2",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 3,
        "LocationTitle": "L 3",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 4,
        "LocationTitle": "L 4",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationTitle": "L 5",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 6,
        "LocationTitle": "L 6",
        "CountryCode": "HIJ",
        "Country": "V"
    }
];

var uData = [];

$.each(data, function(i){
 if(uData.indexOf(data[i].Country) < 0)
   uData.push(data[i].Country);
})

console.log(uData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just `loop` through the data `object` & check for duplicate element using `indexOf` in an `array` with unique country.

Comment: Tks for the comment, I populate the dropdown "country" using the following codes and wondering if it can be simplified?

Comment: var maps_country = $("#country");
        maps_country.get(0).options.length = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var uData = [];
        $.each(data, function (i) {
            if ($.grep(uData, function (e) { return e.CountryCode == data[i].CountryCode; }).length == 0)
                uData.push({ CountryCode: data[i].CountryCode, Country: data[i].Country });
        })
        for (var key in uData) {
            maps_country.get(0).options[count] = new Option(uData[key].Country, uData[key].CountryCode);
            count++;
        }

Comment: @Trowa.. Can you create a **jsfiddle**, it very difficult to understand like this?

Comment: hi, pls try this but it seems not working. https://jsfiddle.net/yp1btjb3/1/

Comment: @Trowa. Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/yp1btjb3/2/ . Mistake was with the **ID**, in `JavaScript` **ID** was **country** where as in `HTML` **ID** was **map-country**.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in plain Javascript.

```js
const arrayOfJson = [
    {
        "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationTitle": "L",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 2,
        "LocationTitle": "L 2",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 3,
        "LocationTitle": "L 3",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 4,
        "LocationTitle": "L 4",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationTitle": "L 5",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 6,
        "LocationTitle": "L 6",
        "CountryCode": "HIJ",
        "Country": "V"
    }
]

const uniqueCountries = []

arrayOfJson.forEach(val => {
  if (uniqueCountries.indexOf(val.Country) === -1) {
    uniqueCountries.push(val.Country)
  }
})

console.log(uniqueCountries)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can one-line it with `reduce`.

```js
let ar = [
    {
        "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationTitle": "L",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 2,
        "LocationTitle": "L 2",
        "CountryCode": "ABC",
        "Country": "G"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 3,
        "LocationTitle": "L 3",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 4,
        "LocationTitle": "L 4",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationTitle": "L 5",
        "CountryCode": "EFG",
        "Country": "M"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 6,
        "LocationTitle": "L 6",
        "CountryCode": "HIJ",
        "Country": "V"
    }
];

console.log(ar.reduce( (p, c) => p.indexOf(c.Country) === -1 ? p.concat([c.Country]) : p, []));
```